# QLabel text not selectble even when i set Qt::TextSelectableByMouse inside QStyledItemDelegate

Tags: c++, qt, delegates

I have a simple item delegate of `QStyledItemDelegate` type and inside its paint method I have this code. It renders fine, but the main thing here is that I would like the text to be selectable for copy, and this doesn't work.

```
void ItemDelegate::paintBody( QPainter* painter,
                              const QStyleOptionViewItem& option,
                              const QModelIndex& index ) const
{
    painter->save();                                    

    QLabel *l = new QLabel();
    l->setTextFormat(Qt::RichText);
    l->setTextInteractionFlags(Qt::TextSelectableByMouse);
    l->setGeometry(option.rect);
    l->setText("This is test");
    l->setStyleSheet("QLabel { background-color : transparent; }");
    l->render(painter, option.rect.topLeft());

    painter->restore();   
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because all all you're doing is painting a QLabel.  The QLabel does not 'exist' inside the model view you are calling for, *it is only rendered in the state that you created it*.

You should use

```
QStyle::drawControl( ControlElement element,
                     const QStyleOption* option,
                     QPainter* painter,
                     const QWidget* widget = 0 ) const;
```

to draw the label. Do not create a new `QLabel` everytime you need to paint it, not only is this inefficient, you have also created the mother of all memory leaks by not deleting it...

More importantly though, selecting text should really be a part of the editor delegate, so you should be overriding

```
QWidget* QAbstractItemDelegate::createEditor( QWidget* parent,
                                              const QStyleOptionViewItem& option,
                                              const QModelIndex& index ) const;
```

to return a widget that can display editable rich text.

Comment: can you please give me simple code example or point me to example?
Thanks Allot

Comment: I think this covers everything you need: http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/itemviews-stardelegate.html